# How can I emit sockets from anywhere in my app outside the callback of the connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically as the title says how can I emit sockets to the front end from any route?

E.g. Say I have a route

```
route.get("/queue", function(req, res) {
    socket.emit("add queue", "username");
});

route.get("/queue/leave", function(req, res) {
    socket.emit("leave queue", "username");
});
```

Or do I have to do everything from within the asynchronous callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the user's socket id in their session or a global, this should demonstrate the basic idea:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var users = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   io.on('register', function(user) {
      users[user] = socket.id;
   });
});

route.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  ...
  req.session.user_id = user_id;
});

route.get("/queue/leave", function(req, res) {
   var socketId = users[req.session.user_id];
   io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('alert', 'whatup?');
});
```

Client side:

```
socket.emit('register', user_id);
```

Comment: Where am I getting io.sockets from?